# How to dynamically grab object keys and use the keys as part of a method?

Tags: javascript, object, search, methods, javascript-objects

I would like to create the filter function to dynamically search through each key for the user search results. How can I do this without hardcoding each key.

```
const data = [
  { title: "title1", body: "body1", footer: "footer1" },
   { title: "title2", body: "body2", footer: "footer2" },
   { title: "title3", body: "body3", footer: "footer3" },
];

const search = 'footer1'

 const filter = data.filter(
      (item) => item.title.includes(search) || item.body.includes(search) || item.footer.includes(search)
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each object that you loop over in the `.filter()` callback, you can grab all of its values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), then you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on this array to check if any of the values within this array contain the `search` string:

```js
const data = [ { title: "title1", body: "body1", footer: "footer1" }, { title: "title2", body: "body2", footer: "footer2" }, { title: "title3", body: "body3", footer: "footer3" }, ];

const search = 'footer1';
const filter = data.filter(
  (item) => Object.values(item).some(val => val.includes(search))
);
console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for...in` loop to access each prop on the item object.

```
const data = [
  { title: "title1", body: "body1", footer: "footer1" },
  { title: "title2", body: "body2", footer: "footer2" },
  { title: "title3", body: "body3", footer: "footer3" },
];

const search = 'footer1'

const filter = data.filter(
   (item) => {
      for(const prop in item){
        if(item[prop].includes(search)){
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
});

console.log(filter)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all the keys(using Object.keys) inside the filter and check the value for each key.

```js
const data = [
  { title: "title1", body: "body1", footer: "footer1" },
  { title: "title2", body: "body2", footer: "footer2" },
  { title: "title3", body: "body3", footer: "footer3" },
];

const search = "filter1";

const filter = data.filter((item) => {
  for (key of Object.keys(item)) {
    if (item[key].includes(search)) {
      return item[key].includes(search);
    }
  }
});

console.log(filter);
```